# Dynamically getting TensorFlow type by string?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm dynamically casting my tensor into different types based on what the input type string is.

How do I get `tf.float64` from a string `'float64'`? I tried `tf.getattr('float64')`, but `tf` is a module that has no `getattr` method.

I'm hacking it by creating a lookup for now, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself:

```
tf.dtypes.as_dtype('float32')
```